# How do I make a python flask route that displays a certain row of a .csv file depending on button pressed

Tags: html, css, csv

I am trying to make a Python Flask route and html page that will display a certain row on my CSV file depending on the button pressed. Go to [this](http://ethankbdca.pythonanywhere.com/pythonforum) link for a better understanding.

Let me sum it up. I am displaying 2 columns out of 3 on the link above and when you click one of the underlined words it is displaying the third column. I want to only display the third column for whatever row is pressed on the previous page. How do i do this?

Here is the html page for the main display:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"/>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<style>
a {
text-decoration: none;
}

body {
background-color: darkblue;
color: white;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin: 0;
}

a.nounderline {
text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
font-size: 40px;
margin: 5;
}

p {
font-size: 20px;
color: darkgrey;
margin-top: 20px;
}

table { 
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}

tr.border_bottom td {
border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}

th, td {
padding: 10px;
text-align: left;
border-bottom: 3px solid #ddd;
border-top: 3px solid #ddd;
}

.container {
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
padding: 5px;
width: 1250px;
}

.nav-link {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
margin-top: 65px;
}

.nav-link ul {
background-color: #000;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 3px;
list-style: none;
display: flex;
}

.nav-link li a {
color: #eee;
font-size: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 0 10px;
white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-link li + li a {
border-left: 1px dotted #666;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <h2 size="8" style="font-family:sans-serif"><b>Python Code</b> 
</h2>
        <p>Make use of this database of Python code to improve your current projects</p>
    </div>
        <div class="nav-link">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/forums">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/pythonforum">Forums</a></li>
                <li><a href="/countdown">Countdown</a></li>
                <li><a href="/addpythoncode">Add Python Code</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
<br/>
    <table width="90%">
    {% for x in pythonforumdata:  %}
        <tr>
            <td width=20%><a href='/pythoncode' >{{ x[0] }}</a></td>
            <td width=20%> {{ x[1] }} </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code on the other page that I want to only display 1 row:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <style>
body {
background-color: darkblue;
color: white;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin: 0;
}

a.nounderline {
text-decoration: none;
}

h1 {
font-size: 40px;
margin: 5;
}

tr.border_bottom td {
border-bottom:1pt solid black;
}

th, td {
border-top: 3px solid #ddd;
}

  </style>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css"/>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table width="90%">
   {% for x in pythoncode:  %}
   <tr>
        <h1 align='center' size="6"> {{ x[1]  }}'Code </h1>
        <td width=20%> {{ x[2] }} </td>
   </tr>
   {% endfor %}
</table><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are the routes:

```
@app.route('/pythonforum')
def pythonforum():
myfile=open("/home/Ethankbdca/mysite/pythonforum.csv", "r")
# codename,name,code
reader = csv.reader(myfile)
headers = next(reader, None)
pythonforumdata = []
for x in reader:
    # 0-codename; 1-name; 2-code
    tup = (x[0],x[1],x[2])
    pythonforumdata.append(tup)
return render_template('pythonforum.html', pythonforumdata=pythonforumdata)

@app.route('/pythoncode')
def pythoncode():
myfile=open("/home/Ethankbdca/mysite/pythonforum.csv", "r")
# codename,name,code
reader = csv.reader(myfile)
headers = next(reader, None)
pythoncode = []
for x in reader:
    # 0-codename; 1-name; 2-code
    tup = (x[0],x[1],x[2])
    pythoncode.append(tup)
return render_template('pythoncode.html', pythoncode=pythoncode)
```

So if anyone can help me figure out what I can clean up and fix to make this work I would greatly appreciate that.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Where is the link? What is the code that you have tried so far? Please visit [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I added it. the page is getting random lines added as i am fiddling with it.